# nullity of the second fundamental group of a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Can anyone tell me why it is that Lie groups seem to have their second fundamental group $\pi_2(G)$ equal to $0$, or provide me with a link to an article or a book reference?

I came across this fact reading an article where the author considers principal $G$ bundles with $G$ a simply connected simple group.

thank you

Comment: For complex reductive groups, one can reduce to its maximal compact subgroup. See GTM98, p.153, p.225.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [Homotopy groups of Lie groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups)