# How to calculate the first and second homotopy groups of the following space constructed from $U(4)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, mp.mathematical-physics

In solving a physics problem, I came across a weird topological space constructed from $U(4)$, the group of $4\times4$ unitary matrices. I want to know the first two homotopy groups of it. Here is how it is defined:

Consider the set $X$ of matrices in $U(4)$
$$X=\{F\in U(4):F=N\Lambda\},$$
where $\Lambda$ is any diagonal unitary matrix, and $N$ has the block form
$$N=\begin{bmatrix}A&A\\B&-B\end{bmatrix},$$
where $A$ and $B$ are $2\times2$ matrices. This, of course, means $N$ must be also unitary, and $A,B$ must satisfy $AA^\dagger=BB^\dagger=\frac{1}{2} I$. 
We can form the quotient space $M=X/\sim$, where $F_1\sim F_2$ if $F_1=F_2\Lambda$, $\Lambda$ being any diagonal unitary matrix.

Is there a way to calculate $\pi_1(M)$ and $\pi_2(M)$?

Comment: Did you define N correctly? It does not look very unitary if, say, A = Id and B = 0.

Comment: @JohannesNordström: I meant N has that form and N is unitary at the same time. In other words, $AA^\dagger=BB^\dagger=\frac{1}{2} I$

Comment: $M$ doesn't look like a subspace of $U(4)$ ($X$ does).

Comment: @FernandoMuro: You might be right. I'm really not sure if it is a subspace, let me edit the post.

Comment: Another description for $M$ is $(U(2)\times U(2))/D$, where $D$ is the subgroup of (unitary) diagonal matrices, acting diagonally on both factors.

Comment: @MarcoGolla: This looks like a promising simplification, but I just started peeking into some general homotopy theory so I'm not able to tell if an answer is immediate using this simplification, would you care to elaborate?

Comment: $M$ should also be the quotient of the set of $N$s by the action of the diagonals (inside that set). An easy computation shows that this is the quotient in my previous comment. In turn, this should be equal to $U(2)/D \times U(2)$, which should be $S^2\times U(2)$.

Comment: @MarcoGolla: It'd be nice if you can expand it into an answer, it is a shame that I'm quite ignorant about the machinery related.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can compute them, and $\pi_1(M) = \mathbb{Z}$, $\pi_2(M) = \mathbb{Z}$.

The way I see it, there are three steps in the proof. For convenience, let me call $Y = U(2)\times U(2)$ the set of $N$s of the form above.

1. Instead of looking at $X/\sim$, let's look at $Y/\sim$ (where I denote with the same symbol the relation on $X$ and its restriction on $Y$). Topologically, this is exactly the same, so the result is still $M$.
2. Notice that $Y/\sim$ is simply $U(2)\times U(2)$ quotiented by the diagonal action of the diagonal subgroup $D$ of $U(2)$. From this it follows that $M$ is $(U(2)/D)\times U(2)$ (this does not hold at the group level, if you're quotienting by a normal subgroup, but it holds at the topological level).
3. $D = U(1)\times U(1)$, and since $\mathbb{CP}^n = U(n+1)/(U(1)\times U(n))$, so $U(2)/D = S^2$.

From this, since $\pi_1(S^2)$ and $\pi_2(U(2))$ are both trivial (the latter is a general fact for Lie groups, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups)), and $\pi_2(S^2)$ and $\pi_1(U(2))$ are both infinite cyclic.

---

The first two steps are more or less just general topology, while the third is apparently well-known.

You can also convince yourself that 3. is true since you can see a "fibration" of $U(2)/D$ over $S^1$ such that the generic fiber is $S^1$ and there's one exceptional fiber which is $S^0$ (though this is not a proof, of course).

Comment: Thanks and +1. I'll need to digest this and come back to it after I learn some more homotopy theory

Comment: And just to confirm, this would mean $\pi_1=Z$ and $\pi_2=Z$, right?

Comment: Yes, that follows. Let me add it to the answer.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Done. Just curious, what is popping up?

Comment: I meant that the question would continue appearing periodically among the first questions in the forum, and this is not desirable for questions which are already answered. Besides, Marco deserves some credit for this.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Thanks. In any case, I think the question was popping up because of the edits (and it's partly my fault -- apologies for that).

Comment: @MarcoGolla I mean't in the future.

Comment: Hi Marco, I just tried to follow your argument in detail, and I had difficulty verifying the claim $Y/\sim\cong (U(2)/D)\times U(2)$. For $Y/\sim$ we are identifying $(A,B)\sim(A\Lambda, B\Lambda)$ where $\Lambda$ is any 2 by 2 diagonal unitray matrix, while it seems for $(U(2)/D)\times U(2)$ we are identifying $(A,B)\sim(A\Lambda, B)$, how do I see there is a homeomorphism between them? Is there an explicit construction?

Comment: Yes, there is an explicit bijection $Y/\sim \; \to (U/D)\times U$, given by $(A,B)\mapsto (A,BA^{-1})$. (Gergő Pintér pointed this out to me.)

Comment: Ah, thanks. For $U(2)/D\cong S^2$, I guess an explicit construction would be $A\mapsto A/\sqrt{\det A}\in SU(2)$,then followed by a Hopf map?

Comment: And sorry if this is naive, I'm also having trouble proving point 1 rigorously, clearly we have the commutative diagram $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Y @>{i}>> X;\\
@V{q_2}VV@VV{q_1} V\\
Y/\sim @>{f}>>X/\sim
\end{CD},$$ where $i$ is inclusion, $q_1,q_2$ are quotient maps, and $f$ is the induced map, it is easy to prove f is bijective and continuous, but I failed to prove it is a homeomorphism. If I can prove $q_1\circ i$ is a quotient map , then it should be done, but my point-set topology failed me.