# Must a continuous variation through compact simply connected Lie groups preserve topology

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Let $S$ be the vector space of multilinear maps from $V\times V$ to $V$. Let $L:\mathbb{I}\rightarrow S$ be a continuous map such that for every $t$ we have that $L(t)$ is a Lie bracket on $V$. For every $t$, let $G_t$ be the simply connected Lie group whose Lie algebra is $(V,L(t))$. It is given that $G_t$ is compact for every $t$.

**Question:** Must $G_0$ and $G_1$ be diffeomorphic ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in fact in this situation you have more, all the Lie algebras $(V, L(t))$ (which I denote by $\mathfrak{g}_t$ to abbreviate) are isomorphic:

Let $G$ be the simply connected Lie group integrating a finite dimensional real Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $W$ be a finite dimensional representation of $G$, and write $W$ also for the induced Lie algebra representation of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Then the differentiable Lie group cohomology of $G$ with values in $W$ vanishes in positive degrees (this can be proven by averaging cocycles with respect to a bi-invariant Haar measure to obtain primitives for them).

The group $G$ is 2-connected (connected and simply connected by assumption, and $\pi_2(G)=0$ holds for any Lie group <s>by a result of Hopf</s> - see edit comment at the bottom), and so there is an isomorphism induced by the so-called Van est map in degrees up to 2, between differentiable Lie group and Lie algebra cohomology with values in $W$:

$$VE: H^k_\mathrm{diff}(G,W)\stackrel{\cong}{\to} H^k(\mathfrak{g},W),\ \ \ k=0,1,2$$

In particular, considering $W$ to be the adjoint representation of a Lie algebra on itself, one conclusion is that, in the setting of the question, $H^2(\mathfrak{g}_t, \mathfrak{g}_t)=0$.

A result of Nijenhuis-Richardson says that any Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $H^2(\mathfrak{g}, \mathfrak{g})=0$ is rigid, i.e., nearby Lie algebras to $\mathfrak{g}$ are isomorphic to it, where nearby is with respect to the topology you have on $S$. One possible place to read about this is the following survey:
*M. Crainic, F. Schätz and I. Struchiner, [A survey on stability and rigidity results for Lie algebras](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.indag.2014.07.015), Indagationes Mathematicae, 25(2014), 957-976.* Theorem 5.3 there is the rigidity result.

Since every $\mathfrak{g_t}$ is rigid and the path is continuous, they will end up being isomorphic, and so $G_t$ are also isomorphic Lie groups.

Edit: the result of Hopf I had in mind only guarantees finite $\pi_2(G)$. But the result that $\pi_2(G)=0$ is true, actual proofs and references for the result are in this Mathoverflow question: [Homotopy groups of Lie groups](https://mathoverflow.net/q/8957/104042)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do we also have the same result for symmetric spaces (instead of lie groups) if we consider instead a deformation of Lie Tripple systems (instead of a deformation of lie algebras) ?

Comment: "and $\pi_2(G)=0$ holds for any Lie group by a result of Hopf": What is a reference for this result of Hopf?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi let me give a Mathoverflow reference for this, because it has both references for the result, some proofs right there, and a lot of interesting discussion (in my view): https://mathoverflow.net/q/8957/104042 .

I think I was wrong about attributing it to Hopf, what I had in mind his result only implies finite $\pi_2$, as explained in this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/8996/104042 .

I don't know who first proved it. Some of the references there are  "Representations of compact Lie groups" by Bröcker and tom Dieck and Milnor's book on Morse theory.

Comment: @Amr That's an interesting question (to me at least)! I'm not very familiar with the setting but I looked a bit into what I could find in the literature.

There is a cohomology (Yamaguti cohomology) for Lie triple systems (Lts) that when using the Lts itself as the module (analogous to the adjoint for Lie algebras) controls the deformations of the Lts. [Kubo, Taniguchi, A controlling cohomology of the deformation theory of Lie triple systems](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2004.01.005)

 If $H^3$ vanishes, then the Lts is rigid in some sense, see theorem 2 in that paper.

Comment: What I did not see, and don't know about at all, are ways to guarantee that H^3 vanishes. 

I don't know if, by analogy, this could some times be implied by some assumptions on symmetric spaces, be it compactness or some sort of connectedness (perhaps 3-connectedness in this case?).

Comment: Borel, [Groupes d’homotopie des  groups de Lie. I](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=SHC_1949-1950__2__A12_0),  attributes the theorem: $\pi_2(G)=0$ to Élie Cartan  (Theorem 1(2) on page 12-05). He refers to Cartan’s book:  La topologie des groupes de Lie. Exposés de géométrie Nr. 8.  Actualités Scient. Industr. 358 Paris: Hermann & Cie. 28 p. (1936).

Comment: Thank you for the reference!